# How to use login using parse in android

Tags: android

I am doing a login application and I use parse for database but the problem is when i try to login in my application it gives me invalid userID and password but i write the same record that i have in parse does anyone know what is the problem in my code and what should i do ?! here is my code from android studio.

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
EditText userID,password;
TextView txtuser,txtpassword;
Button login;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Parse.initialize(this, "SMXvtOppMAR1x2NsG10eJ4vr8qKCOLKKDilnv4",
            "Ro7d1xT87p7GvnAIguHEhu7V7CuVPCEqbqY7qs");

    userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserId);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    txtuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
    txtpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butLogin);

login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("SUPERVISOR");
    query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_ID", userID.getText().toString());
    query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_Password", password);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject result, ParseException arg1) {

            if (result != null) {
                // Go to the supervisor screen
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,
                        SupervisorScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                // invalid user name
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid user name and password",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_Password", password);
```

is probably wrong. `password` is an EditText but you'll need its content. Try using

```
query.whereEqualTo("Supervisor_Password", password.getText().toString());
```

instead.